# SortBy doesn't work in datatable dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Javascript:

```
dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table')
    .dimension(date)
    //...
    .group(function (d) {
        var format = d3.time.format('%B, %Y');
        return format(d.date);
    })
    .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.date;
    })
    .order(d3.ascending);
```

SortBy doesn't something effect and order too. How to fix this problem?

All code sample on https://jsfiddle.net/u073mab0/2/

Comment: Your example works fine for me within the groups. Date is sorted ascending. If I switch the sortBy accessor to `return -d.date;`, it sorts descending. Same if I switch the ordering. Is your problem the sorting of the groups? Those are also sorted according to the order, but since they are text, they are sorted as text. You could use a custom ordering function to handle that, I suppose.

Comment: On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvLb2w31/2/) fix ordering for groups. Works for me. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the dc.js version you are using an old version of dc   sort works on FF/IE but not on chrome.

Well that's the reason why @EthanJewett is able to see it sorted, because he may be seeing this in FF or IE.

And I was not able to see because I was on chrome.

Please use a new version of dc.js `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.0-dev/dc.js`

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jvLb2w31/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This help for sorting in a group, thx.  But groups are sorted "random":)

Comment: It's sorted alphabetically, as Ethan mentioned. Use `.order` to affect this, although I don't see a way to sort by Date object and then format as string.

Comment: Very interesting that it just doesn't work in Chrome. I looked at it in Safari, for the record.

Comment: @Gordon can you modify [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jvLb2w31/1/) for using `.order` method?